# go from work to home on foot / go home from work on foot / come back from work on foot

Tags: sentence-usage

I know that the first sentence and the second one are used in English. How about the others? Maybe, some examples are grammatically correct, but awkward in English.

> I usually walk home from work.
>
> I usually go home on foot.

> I usually **go from work to home on foot**.

> I usually **go home from work on foot**.

> I usually **come back from work on foot**.

Comment: Why did you think some might be awkward?

Comment: They have too much words. If all is fine, I'm happy. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are all fine (except the last one which is a little clumsy).

As you said in comment, you feel that they have too many words. So go with the shortest one:

> I usually walk home from work.

There's no need to say "walk *back* home", as this is what "walk home" means, idiomatically. And "walk" is more succinct than "on foot". This really is the most natural way to say what you are trying to.

Comment: The last one is "come back from work on foot". Is it clumsy or you just said it about "walk back home"?

Comment: I regard 'go from work to home' as clumsy.